# Authenticating username and password from a MongoDB in extjs framework project loginView

Tags: javascript, mongodb, post, extjs

I have a LoginView in my extjs project. I pass the data from this view to my LoginController and then using an Ajax Post call I try to match the two fields [username , password] from loginview text fields with the same fields in my MongoDb database.Here is my LoginView

```
   Ext.define('Eits.view.LoginView', {
extend : 'Ext.window.Window',
title : 'Login - Netowrk Monitoring System',
height : 300,
width : 300,
layout : 'fit',
id : 'loginView',

closable : false,
resizable : false,
modal : true,

okBtn : null,
unameField : null,
passField : null,

initComponent : function() {

    this.okBtn = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
        text : 'Login'
    });

    this.unameField = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
        itemId : 'username',
        fieldLabel : 'Username',
        allowBlank : false,
        enableKeyEvents : true,
        focus : true,
        msgTarget: 'under',
        maxLength:25
    });

    this.passField = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
        fieldLabel : 'Password',
        inputType : 'password',
        allowBlank : false,
        enableKeyEvents : true,
        maxLength:12,
        msgTarget: 'under'
    });

    var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        layout : {
            type : 'vbox',
            align : 'stretch'
        },
        border : false,
        bodyPadding : 10,

        fieldDefaults : {
            labelAlign : 'top',
            labelWidth : 100,
            labelStyle : 'font-weight:bold'
        },
        items : [ this.unameField, this.passField ]
    });

    Ext.apply(this, {
        items : [ form ],
        buttons : [ this.okBtn ]
    });
    this.callParent(arguments);
},

getLoginBtn : function() {
    return this.okBtn;
},

getUsername : function() {
    return this.unameField.getValue();
},

getPassword : function() {
    return this.passField.getValue();
},

getUsernameField : function() {
    return this.unameField;
},

getPasswordField : function() {
    return this.passField;
},

clearFields : function() {
    this.unameField.reset();
    this.passField.reset();
}

});
```

Here is my Login controller:

```
                    Ext.define('Eits.controller.LoginController', {
extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
requires : [ 'Eits.view.LoginView' ],

view : Ext.create('Eits.view.LoginView'),
id : 'loginController',
constructor : function() {
    this.callParent(arguments);
},

isStarted : false,
bind : function() {
    this.view.getLoginBtn().on('click', this.doLoginClicked, this);
    this.view.getPasswordField().on('keyup', function(field, event) {
        console.log("pressd");
        if (event.getKey() == event.ENTER) {
            this.doLoginClicked();
        }
    }, this);
    this.view.getUsernameField().on('keyup', function(field, event) {
        if (event.getKey() == event.ENTER) {
            this.doLoginClicked();
        }
    }, this);
},

localStorageProvider : null,
/**
 * 
 */
start : function() {
    if (this.isStarted == false) {
        this.isStarted = true;
        this.bind();
        this.localStorageProvider = Ext.create('Ext.state.CookieProvider', {
            expires : null
        });
    }
    if(this.localStorageProvider != null) {
        var user = this.localStorageProvider.get('user');
        var pass = this.localStorageProvider.get('pass');
        if(user == 'admin' && pass == 'admin') {
            this.startMain();
            return;
        }
    }

    this.view.show();
    //this.view.getUsernameField().focus(false, 2000);
},

logout : function() {
    if(this.localStorageProvider != null) {
        this.localStorageProvider.set('user', null);
        this.localStorageProvider.set('pass', null);
    }
    this.start();
},

startMain : function() {
    Eits.store.DataStore.init();
    Eits.Factory.getAppController().start();
},

doLoginClicked : function() {
    console.log("button pressed this time");
    var name = this.view.getUsername();
    var pass = this.view.getPassword();

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'php/login.php',
        method:'post',
        params: {
            user: name,
            password: pass},
            success: function(conn, response, options, eOpts) {

                var result = Ext.JSON.decode(conn.responseText, true); 

                if (!result){ 
                    result = {};
                    result.success = false;
                    result.msg = conn.responseText;
                }

                if (result.success) { 

                    login.close(); 


                } else {
                    console.log("inside failure");
                    console.log(conn);
                    console.log(response);

                    Ext.Msg.show({
                        title:'Fail!',
                        msg: result.msg, 
                        icon: Ext.Msg.ERROR,
                        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK

                    });
                }
            },
            failure: function(conn, response, options, eOpts) {
                console.log("inside failure");

                  Ext.Msg.show({
                        title:'Error!',
                        msg: conn.responseText,
                        icon: Ext.Msg.ERROR,
                        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                    });
                }
        });
    }
});
```

I made a connection to my MongoDb in my db.php as follows:

```
      <?php 
      $m = new MongoClient();
      echo "Connection to database successfully";
     // select a database
      $db = $m->EnlyticaDb;
      echo "Database EnlyticaDb selected";
      }
      ?>
```

and finally I do the check in Login.php as Follows :

```
          require("db/db.php"); 

          session_start(); 

         $userName = $_POST['user']; 
         $pass = $_POST['password']; 
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('insidelogin.php');             </script>";
         $userName = stripslashes($userName); 
         $pass = stripslashes($pass);         

         $user = $db->collection->findOne(array("username" => $userName, "password" => $pass));
         if ($user->count() > 0){
         $_SESSION['authenticated'] = "yes"; 
         $_SESSION['username'] = $userName;  

         $result['success'] = true; 
         $result['msg'] = 'User authenticated!'; 
         return $result;
}
else
{
$result['success'] = false; 
$result['msg'] = 'Incorrect user or password.';
return null;
}
 echo json_encode($result);
```

When i run the project and try to login with the same username and password as stored , it pops up the error popup from "success: " ,i.e,

```
           Ext.Msg.show({
                        title:'Fail!',
                        msg: result.msg, 
                        icon: Ext.Msg.ERROR,
                        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK

                    });
```

This means the response is returned but it is not returning success.How can I do the authentication and  then display the next View.

Comment: checked the response??

Comment: @Yellen it simply posts the login.php in the repsonse .Here is a screenshot:
http://gyazo.com/a5e0a99c92422d1f39cfafd4010b2047

Comment: I mean, check what is in the response object? Probably debug and see what and why your response is like that.\

Comment: check whats in ajax response maybe that will help ..